# QGIS 2.2.0 install via OSGeo4W overwrote/lost qGIS ver. 2.0

Tags: qgis, installation

Just installed ver 2.2.0 Valmiera through the OSGeo4W advanced installer for a test drive.  It overwrote existing ver 2.0 in the process. Still want to have the previous to work from.

How can i get QGIS ver 2.0 back without problems in running the new release?

Comment: QGIS 2.2 Valmiera is the new stable release and replaces 2.0. Thus you should normally be fine. If you still want to reinstall the older version you need to look for the 2.0 binaries on the QGIS server and install them manually i guess

Answer (score 1):

look at http://qgis.org/downloads/ and download the standalone installer
QGIS-OSGEO4W-2.0.1-3-Setup-x86.exe (32bit) or .....Setup-x86_64.exe (64 bit)

Comment: The only odd thing that remains is that the .qgis file extension is always asigned to the latest installed QGIS version. So just clicking on the project file might open it with the version you do not want.

Comment: **UPDATE** You can click on `../apps/qgis/bin/qgis.reg` of the desired version to change the default startup when doubleclicking a project file.